# Recursive backtracking in Java for solving a crossword

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, backtracking, recursive-backtracking

I need to solve a crossword given the initial grid and the words *(words can be used more than once or not at all)*.

The initial grid looks like that:

```
++_+++
+____+
___+__
+_++_+
+____+
++_+++
```

Here is an example word list:

```
pain
nice
pal
id
```

The task is to fill the placeholders *(horizontal or vertical having length > 1)* like that:

```
++p+++
+pain+
pal+id
+i++c+
+nice+
++d+++
```

Any correct solution is acceptable, and it's guaranteed that there's a solution.

---

In order to start to solve the problem, I store the grid in 2-dim. char array and I store the words by their length in the list of sets: `List<Set<String>> words`, so that e.g. the words of length 4 could be accessed by `words.get(4)`

Then I extract the location of all placeholders from the grid and add them to the list (stack) of placeholders:

```
class Placeholder {
    int x, y; //coordinates 
    int l; // the length
    boolean h; //horizontal or not
    public Placeholder(int x, int y, int l, boolean h) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.l = l;
        this.h = h;
    }
}
```

The main part of the algorithm is the `solve()` method:

```
char[][] solve (char[][] c, Stack<Placeholder> placeholders) {
    if (placeholders.isEmpty())
        return c;

    Placeholder pl = placeholders.pop();
    for (String word : words.get(pl.l)) {
        char[][] possibleC = fill(c, word, pl); // description below
        if (possibleC != null) {
            char[][] ret = solve(possibleC, placeholders);
            if (ret != null)
                return ret;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Function `fill(c, word, pl)` just returns a new crossword with the current word written on the current placeholder *pl*. If *word* is incompatible with *pl*, then function returns null.

```
char[][] fill (char[][] c, String word, Placeholder pl) {

    if (pl.h) {
        for (int i = pl.x; i < pl.x + pl.l; i++)
            if (c[pl.y][i] != '_' && c[pl.y][i] != word.charAt(i - pl.x))
                return null;
        for (int i = pl.x; i < pl.x + pl.l; i++)
            c[pl.y][i] = word.charAt(i - pl.x);
        return c;

    } else {
        for (int i = pl.y; i < pl.y + pl.l; i++)
            if (c[i][pl.x] != '_' && c[i][pl.x] != word.charAt(i - pl.y))
                return null;
        for (int i = pl.y; i < pl.y + pl.l; i++)
            c[i][pl.x] = word.charAt(i - pl.y);
        return c;
    }
}
```

### Here is the full code on [Rextester](http://rextester.com/MEYRW1661).

---

The problem is that my backtracking algorithm doesn't work well. Let's say this is my initial grid:

```
++++++
+____+
++++_+
++++_+
++++_+
++++++
```

And this is the list of words:

```
pain
nice
```

My algorithm will put the word `pain` vertically, but then when realizing that it was a wrong choice it will backtrack, but by that time the initial grid will be already changed and the number of placeholders will be reduced. How do you think the algorithm can be fixed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solving crosswords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44606961/solving-crosswords)

Comment: Hahahahaha, That is what I call crossfire :DDD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be solved in 2 ways:

- Create [a deep copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564832/how-do-i-do-a-deep-copy-of-a-2d-array-in-java) of the matrix at the start of `fill`, modify and return that (leaving the original intact).

  Given that you already pass around the matrix, this wouldn't require any other changes.

  This is simple but fairly inefficient as it requires copying the matrix every time you try to fill in a word.
- Create an `unfill` method, which reverts the changes made in `fill`, to be called at the end of each for loop iteration.

  ```
  for (String word : words.get(pl.l)) {
      if (fill(c, word, pl)) {
          ...
          unfill(c, word, pl);
      }
  }
  ```

  Note: I changed `fill` a bit as per my note below.

  Of course just trying to erase all letter may erase letters of other placed words. To fix this, we can keep a count of how many words each letter is a part of.

  More specifically, have a `int[][] counts` (which will also need to be passed around or be otherwise accessible) and whenever you update `c[x][y]`, also increment `counts[x][y]`. To revert a placement, decrease the count of each letter in that placement by 1 and only remove letters with a count of 0.

  This is somewhat more complex, but much more efficient than the above approach.

  In terms of code, you might put something like this in `fill`:
  (in the first part, the second is similar)

  ```
  for (int i = pl.x; i < pl.x + pl.l; i++)
      counts[pl.y][i]++;
  ```

  And `unfill` would look something like this: (again for just the first part)

  ```
  for (int i = pl.x; i < pl.x + pl.l; i++)
      counts[pl.y][i]--;
  for (int i = pl.x; i < pl.x + pl.l; i++)
      if (counts[pl.y][i] == 0)
          c[pl.y][i] = '_';
  // can also just use a single loop with "if (--counts[pl.y][i] == 0)"
  ```

---

Note that, if going for the second approach above, it might make more sense to simply have `fill` return a `boolean` (`true` if successful) and just pass `c` down to the recursive call of `solve`. `unfill` can return `void`, since it can't fail, unless you have a bug.

There is only a single array that you're passing around in your code, all you're doing is changing its name.

See also [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: Do you suggest to put `c = unfill(c, word, pl);` at the end of for loop?

Comment: @gdrt It shouldn't matter either way. `unfill` doesn't even have to return anything. There's only 1 array, passing it to a function doesn't make a copy of it. The "best" approach would be to have `fill` return a `boolean` and `unfill` return `void`. See edit to answer.

Comment: I did everything as you suggested, please look at http://rextester.com/NFDH24126 . You will find the input there. In the output the program leaves one placeholder unsolved.

Comment: Seems like `placeholders.add(pl);` should be added after `unfill`, but it doesn't help :/

Comment: @gdrt See fixed code [here](http://ideone.com/o5u5GO). You need to actually check the return value of fill, and push to placeholders at the end of the loop.

Comment: @gdrt You code also seems to be missing a check to ensure the word and the placeholder are the same length in `fill`.

Comment: Thanks for everything! Actually it's not possible, as I am only looping through the words of length equal to the length of placeholder. Now everything is good except time limit :D But I think it's doable if I change the stack to smth else and also look to the adjacent placeholders instead of trivially popping.

Answer (score 1):

You identified it yourself:

> it will backtrack, but by that time the initial grid will be already
>   changed

That grid should be a local matrix, not a global one.  That way, when you back up with a return of `null`, the grid from the parent call is still intact, ready to try the next word in the `for` loop.

Your termination logic is correct: when you find a solution, immediately pass that grid back up the stack.

Comment: Could you please add the code? Which matrix were you talking about? I think `possibleC` matrix is a local one

Comment: I also believe it's local -- but let's work on debugging technique: what is the "initial grid" you said was already changed?  Have you printed out your master grid at appropriate points to track data flow?

Comment: Please look at the last example, where there are only 2 placeholders. "Initial grid" is when there are no letters on the grid. Then my algorithm chooses a vertical placeholder, then wrongly fills it with the word *pain*, then recurses and there tries to fill the horizontal placeholder with *nice* and fails, then it backtracks and tries to fill the vertical placeholder (1st one), but now it cannot (because there's a bug) as the initial grid is spoiled with the word *pain*

Comment: Right.  Dukeling just gave you a good answer, just what I was trying to lead you toward.